# Let user control line breaks through input in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, line, break

I would like to display a line break every time that the user presses the enter button in the input field. Let me show you this example picture :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyF4R.png

As you can see, the user writes in the input:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

But my application does not recognize those as line breaks and shows everything in one line as shown above the inputs.

This is how my input code looks like:

```
    <TextField
      label="Description"
      variant="outlined"
      id="desc"
      type="text"
      name="Description"
      value={this.state.desc}
      onChange={(e) => {
        this.setState({ typed: true });
        this.setState({ desc: e.target.value });
      }}
      required
      disabled={this.state.loading}
      multiline
    ></TextField>
```

I'm not sure how to render every line break that the user places in the input especially because every change is registered as the value of the description state and even if I use regex to replace line breaks with br it will just show br as a string.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the HTML `<textarea>` form Attribute like this in your text input inside your `<TextField />` component:

```html
<textarea form="usrform" {...props}>{props.value}</textarea>
```

Reference [HTML textarea form Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_form.asp).

Comment: Hello, I really tried to understand what you meant but couldn't. Can you please explain this solution?

Comment: Can you share the code of your `<TextField>` please?